# For any vector fields $V,W$ along a curve $a$, $\frac{d}{dt} \langle V,W \rangle = \langle D_tV,W \rangle+ \langle V,D_tW \rangle$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry

For any vector fields $V,W$ along a curve $a$, $\frac{d}{dt} \langle V,W \rangle =  \langle D_tV,W \rangle+ \langle V,D_tW \rangle$, if the connection is compatible with the given metric, i.e. for any vector fields $X,Y,Z$, $X\langle Y,Z \rangle= \langle \nabla_XY,Z \rangle+\langle X,\nabla_XZ \rangle$.

I propose a proof as follow:

$\frac{d}{dt}\langle V,W \rangle = \dot a(t)\langle V,W \rangle = \langle \nabla_{\dot a(t)}V,W \rangle + \langle V,\nabla_{\dot a(t)}W \rangle  = \langle D_tV,W \rangle + \langle V,D_tW \rangle$.

But, I do not think this is right, because $\nabla_{\dot a(t)}V = D_tV$ only if $V$ is  extendible, here $V$ is only assumed to be a vector field along $a$. How should I fix this problem?

Actually $\frac{d}{dt}\langle V,W \rangle = \dot a(t)\langle V,W \rangle$ also requires that they are extendible vector fields.

Comment: Both sides of the equation depend only on the values of $V,W$ in an arbitrarily small neighbourhood of the point you evaluate at, so you only need to extend $V,W$ locally, which is always possible.

Comment: Do you have any reference for this matter? How to extend it locally?

Comment: The proof you have written is not correct. And it is not correct because the reason you have mentioned. Typically the proof use an orthonormal basis at a point on $a$ and then extend the orthonormal basis (ONB) to an ONB on the whole of $a$ using parallel transport (here you have to use compatibility). Then writing everything with respect to this ONB  and using the product rule at both side we prove this theorem. See Proposition 3.2 of Chapter 2 of Do Carmo's Riemannian geometry book.

Comment: Thank you so much, that really solves my question. Can you paste your comment to form an answer so that I can accept it? @tessellation

Answer (score 2):

We have that $V$ and $W$ are defined along a curve $a(t)$, say
$$
V(t) = Y(a(t)), \; \; \; \; W(t) = Z(a(t)),
$$
then we have that
$$
\frac{DV}{dt} = \nabla_{\frac{da}{dt}}Y,
$$
so let $X(p) = \frac{dc}{dt}|_{t=t_0}$ and assuming $X\langle Y , Z \rangle = \langle \nabla_X Y , Z \rangle + \langle Y , \nabla_{X} Z \rangle$ then we have
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt} \left\langle U , V \right\rangle\bigg|_{t=t_0} &= \frac{d}{dt} \left\langle Y , Z \right\rangle\bigg|_{t=t_0} \\
&= X(p)\left\langle Y , Z\right\rangle_p \\
&= \left\langle \nabla_X(p) Y , Z \right\rangle_p + \left\langle Y , \nabla_X(p) Z\right\rangle_p \\
&= \left\langle \nabla_{\frac{da}{dt}} Y , Z \right\rangle_p + \left\langle Y , \nabla_{\frac{da}{dt}} Z \right\rangle_p \\
&= \left\langle \frac{DV}{dt} , W \right\rangle_p + \left\langle V , \frac{DW}{dt}\right\rangle_p.
\end{align}
$$

Since the result is just being applied in a small enough neighbourhood around $t_0$ we just need to be able to chose vector fields that agree locally, to do that consider a compact interval $J\subset I$ and a coordinate system $(x,U)$ on $M$ such that $a(J) \subset U$ then we have

**Lemma**  Let $g(t)$ be a differentiable function on an open interval containing $J$. Then there exists an $\epsilon > 0 $ and a function $G \in C^{\infty}(M)$ such that
$$
G(a(t)) = g(t), \; \; \forall t, \; \; |t-t_0| < \epsilon
$$

*Sketch of proof*: There is some coordinate function $x^i : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $t \mapsto x^{i}(a(t))$ has nonzero derivative at $t=t_0$, therefore we can invert this to get a function $\eta^i$ such that $t = \eta^i (x^i(a(t))$ in some small interval around $t_0$, so the function $q \rightarrow g(\eta^i(x^i(q))$ is defined and differentiable for $q \in U$ near to $a(t_0)$, so we can then select a function $\tilde{G} \in C^{\infty}(U)$ such that $\tilde{G}(q) = q(\eta^i(x^i(q)))$ for all $q$ in some neighbourhood of $\gamma(t_0)$, also we clearly have
$$
\tilde{G}(a(t)) = g(t),
$$
This can then be extended to some function $G \in C^{\infty}(M)$. Infact using parition of unity arguments it can be extended to a function $G$ agreeing with $g(t)$ along all of $t \in J$. $\square$

So if the vector field $V(t)$ along $a(t)$ is written as $V = \sum_i V^i(t) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ then we can use the Lemma above to  write the component functions $V^i : J \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as $C^{\infty}$ functions $Y^{i}(p)$ agreeing along $a(t)$ giving a vector field $Y \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ with local coordinate expression $\sum_i Y^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ such that around $a(t_0)$ we have $V(t) = Y(a(t))$.

Comment: For your argument to be right, it requires justification that $D_tY|_p$ only depends on $Y(p)$, but I do not see why this should be true. Is it true?

Comment: I think that has tightened it up a bit now? What do you think?

Comment: I am sorry, but I am still a little bit lost. Are your $Y, Z$ vector fields on the manifold? I do not really think it is alway possible to extend a vector field along the curve $a$ to a vector field on the whole manifold.

Comment: In other words, why can you always assume that $V(t) = Y(a(t))$ for some $Y$?

Comment: Yeah I get your concern, I *think* you can argue that if the curve is defined on an interval $I$ and you have a compact subinterval $J$ such that $J$ contains no double points (irregularities etc.) then you can extend a function $g(t)$, $t \in J$ to a function $G \in C^{\infty}(M)$ such that $G(a(t)) = g(t)$, then at least over the image of the compact interval $a(J)$ you can use that to find vector fields in $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ that will agree along the curves.

Comment: Basically if you write $X = \sum X^i (t) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$, where the component functions $X^{i} : J \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ then there is a $C^{\infty}(M)$ function $\tilde{X}^{i}(p)$ such that for $t \in J$ where $J$ is small compact interval you have $\tilde{X}^{i}(a(t)) = X^{i}(t)$, and this is enough because the result we are applying depends only on the value of the vector fields along the curve.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but why is $X(p)\langle Y, Z \rangle_{p}= \frac{d}{dt}\langle Y, Z \rangle \vert_{t=t_{0}}$? In fact, I'm not sure, if I understand clearly what $X(p)\langle Y, Z \rangle_{p}$ is, it looks like a directional derivative of some sort.

Comment: The notation is a bit misleading, you should consider $\langle Y, Z \rangle$ as a function rather evaluated at $p$. Then $X(p) \langle Y, Z \rangle$ is considered as acting $X(p)$ on the funciton $\langle Y, Z \rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an explanation for submanifolds in the Euclidian space (eg surfaces in $E_3$), which explains the geometric meaning of the covariant derivative.

If $M\subset E$ is a submanifold and $a(t)$ a curve on $M$, the operator ${D\over dt}$ on vector fields on $M$ is defined as follows: if $X$ is such a vector field, extend it in a vector field on a neigbourhood of $M$, still denoted by $X$.

Then ${D\over dt} X (a(t_0))$ is the orthogonal projection of the usual derivative ${d\over dt} X (a(t_0))$ onto the tangent space $T_{a(t_0)}M$.

Therefore, if $Y$ is another vector field tangent to $M$,

$<{d\over dt} X (a(t_0)),Y(a(t_0)>=<{D\over dt} X (a(t_0)),Y(a(t_0)>$,

whence the result, as standard calculus in $E$ tells you that :
$d/dt<X(a(t)),Y(a(t))>=<d/dtX(a(t)),Y(a(t))>+<X(a(t)),d/dt Y(a(t))>$

Answer (score 1):

The proof you have written is not correct. And it is not correct because the reason you have mentioned. Typically the proof use an orthonormal basis at a point on $a$ and then extend the orthonormal basis (ONB) to an ONB on the whole of $a$ using parallel transport (here you have to use compatibility). Then writing everything with respect to this ONB and using the product rule at both side we prove this theorem. See Proposition 3.2 of Chapter 2 of Do Carmo's Riemannian geometry book.

Comment: Sorry,  Do Carmo does not really use the definition for compatibility I proposed. The proof you mention is about another equivalent condition.